# Is this Halloween campaign from Pepsi and Coca Cola real?

Tags: consumer-products

For 2013's Halloween, there's an ad on the internet about a Pepsi can with a Coke costume, stating it's “scary”, to which Coca Cola responds with “Everybody wants to be a hero”.

[image: Pepsi vs Coke Halloween 2013]

So far, so good, but the only reference I have been able to find is both images side by side, with a “via 9GAG.com” legend on the side.

Considering that 9GAG is not a reliable source and anybody can upload images there, I'm skeptical about these ads. Are they real? Did Coca Cola really respond in such a way to Pepsi?

Comment: If it only exists on 9GAG, then it's not really a notable claim, is it?

Comment: Sites who are spreading the news: http://voxxi.com/2014/10/29/the-soda-wars-pepsi-versus-coke-for-halloween/ http://laprimeraplana.com.mx/2014/10/29/la-guerra-de-pepsi-y-coca-en-halloween-foto/ http://thenextweb.com/shareables/2013/11/04/pepsi-won-halloween-thanks-to-this-clever-ad/ http://bloggr.in/2013/11/pepsi-coke-soda-wars/

Comment: Wait, I realized this is from 2013. I will edit my question.

Comment: @ChrisW, It would also be nice to know, if Pepsi and Coke aren't responsible, who is? (but that's not the main question, I know)

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez There was a designer who claimed it as his work, and he had several gags like this on his site... Will try to find it.

Comment: Sorry, no luck... Maybe it was also fake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is apparently real.

[This site](http://www.fooddive.com/news/coke-fans-halloween-response-to-pepsi-ad-goes-viral/190208/) and [this site](http://adsoftheworld.com/media/outdoor/pepsi_halloween) claim it's from a specific (Belgian) ad agency.

```
Advertising Agency: Buzz in a Box, Brussels, Belgium  
Creative Directors / Art Directors: Gregory Defay, Quentin Gascard  
Photographer: Jekyll n' Hyde  
Additional credits: Account Manager: Tu Anh Ha  
Published: October 2013
```

The first image doesn't have the 9GAG logo; and "Coca Cola" is mispelled.

That ad agency currently features [a different Pepsi ad](http://www.buzzinabox.be/works_34.html) (showing that the agency has Pepsi as a client).

Comment: I personally doubt whether Coke could produce the second ad: IMO as a joke or parody it is "fair use", but as a commercial advertisement it would be copyright violation.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking something similar. Anyway, I will wait some time if someone can prove whether the second one is real before accepting your answer.